# Отбор строк датасета по нескольким условиям Python

Tags: python, pandas

На вход дан датасет, где id - id пользователя, url - просмотренная страница, timestamp - время просмотра страница.

```
    id  url timestamp
0   a   page_1  2021-10-09 15:46:20
1   a   page_2  2021-10-09 15:47:20
2   a   page_3  2021-10-09 15:48:20
3   a   page_4  2021-10-09 15:49:20
4   a   page_2  2021-10-09 15:50:20
5   b   page_4  2021-10-09 15:18:20
6   b   page_3  2021-10-09 15:21:20
7   b   page_2  2021-10-09 15:22:20
8   b   page_1  2021-10-09 15:24:20
9   b   page_1  2021-10-09 15:26:20
```

Каждый из пользователей **гарантированно** посещает page_2. Необходимо выбрать все, посещенные каждым из пользователем страницы, до page_2. Если пользователь несколько раз посещал page_2, то необходимо включить все страница до **последнего** посещения page_2.
Оригинальный массив очень большой, поэтому хотелось бы найти способ более быстрый чем перебор.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение будет работать только если ваши данные будут иметь следующий формат (называется csv):

```
# файл input.csv
id,url,timestamp
a,page_1,2021-10-09 15:46:20
a,page_2,2021-10-09 15:47:20
a,page_3,2021-10-09 15:48:20
a,page_4,2021-10-09 15:49:20
a,page_2,2021-10-09 15:50:20
b,page_4,2021-10-09 15:18:20
b,page_3,2021-10-09 15:21:20
b,page_2,2021-10-09 15:22:20
b,page_1,2021-10-09 15:24:20
b,page_1,2021-10-09 15:26:20
```

Решение:

```
import pandas as pd


def all_visited_pages_until(page, user_id, df):
    df_by_user = df[(df.id == user_id)]
    df_by_user = df_by_user.sort_values(by="timestamp")
    last_row_index_by_page = df_by_user.url.where(df_by_user.url == page).last_valid_index()

    return df_by_user.loc[:last_row_index_by_page]


def main():
    df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", sep=",")
    print(all_visited_pages_until("page_2", "a", df))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вывод программы:

```
0    page_1
1    page_2
2    page_3
3    page_4
4    page_2
Name: url, dtype: object
```

На выходе получили объект `Series`. Если будет необходимо, его можно будет преобразовать в `list`

===UPD===

Если все страницы имеют вид `page_i` (`i` это соответственно номер), то для оптимизации хранения большого объёма данных можно вместо `page_i` хранить именно `i`.

Для этого перед вызовом функции `all_visited_pages_until` достаточно написать `df.url = df.url.apply(lambda url: int(url.replace("page_", "")))`